# Couchbase vs Amazon Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, couchbase

How can we compare Amazon DynamoDB to Couchbase? Which is better in terms of performance, scalability, availability and fault tolerance ?

Thanks for the help.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: Could you show us what research you have done..

Answer (score 1):

This is too generic & strategical question to be part of stackoverflow and the answer could be either of it depending on use case. However I will just let you know what should be considered while deciding.

Remember Couchbase is a NoSQL software but DynamoDB is a NoSQL database as a service. So comparing them may be not a a great idea.

Couchbase can be hosted in-memory and be blazing fast if hosted in local network inside the datacentre. For DynamoDB you have to host your application in EC2 otherwise network lag would be a bottle neck.Most of the time you may not notice a lag as they promise 2 digit latency i.e. less than 99ms. Advantage of dynamo DB is that you don't manage it for backup and recovery . For couchbase in case you host it it could be a pain while upgrades or downtime when you have to take care of backups and version compatibility of data and balancing data across nodes in cluster.